# Full size keyboard with built in stand for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, keyboard, bluetooth, hardware-recommendation

I'm looking for bluetooth keyboards for use with my iPhone. I'd like a full size keyboard that has a built in iPhone stand. Everything I've found so far with a built in stand is almost full size but not quite. Are there any full size keyboard options with built in iPhone stands? A case for the apple bluetooth keyboard that had a stand built in would also work but I haven't found one of these.

Comment: Hmmm... a keyboard with a built-in dock connector for my iPhone.  I might buy that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've found for this is the [Wing Stand](http://wingstand.com/) with an Apple bluetooth keyboard. while it isn't the most stable setup it works fine for setting the phone on a table along with the keyboard and typing.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, have you taken a look at the Apple iPad Keyboard Dock Wired Keyboard?

It doesn't have a number pad but otherwise is a full sized keyboard that shouldn't even need bluetooth.

Of course I am assuming that it will work with an iPhone even though it was made for an iPad.

Comment: Any bluetooth keyboard will work with an iPhone or iPad.